# Lower weight paint seems to have stronger effect?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to weight paint a shoulder cape to follow an upper arm, but for some reason a part of the mesh that has a weaker weight seems to move more/have a stronger weight when posed. Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can provide any further information about the blender file, or I can just upload it if necessary. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: May be the red area is much more affected by an other bone then the green.

Comment: I didn't think that was the case from some testing, but you were right, I just checked and the neck bone had red weight all over the place, that was the issue